# Ubuntu conda install pydub

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, pydub

I have ubuntu version 15.10 and anaconda version conda 4.4.10.
My problem is I am trying to install the module/package pydub and the command to do that is:
conda install -c auto pydub #(see https://anaconda.org/auto/pydub)

The error message I am getting is this:

Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - gevent
  - pydub
Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

Can you please help, I have run out of ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried executing the suggested command `conda info` ?
It appears that `gevent` and `pydub` packages are in conflict from the output you've provided.
It should work if you resolve the conflict in the dependencies manually by updating `gevent` and then `pydub`.

Comment: conda infor gevent:   gevent 1.2.2 py36_0
-------------------
file name   : gevent-1.2.2-py36_0.tar.bz2
name        : gevent
version     : 1.2.2
build string: py36_0
build number: 0
channel     : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
size        : 1.4 MB
arch        : x86_64
constrains  : ()
date        : 2017-06-07
license     : MIT
md5         : d131d30fa5df2133d6e6c97ed268e120
platform    : linux
subdir      : linux-64
url         : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/gevent-1.2.2-py36_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    greenlet >=0.4.10
    python 3.6*

Comment: thats seems to suggest that I must install greenlet package version 0.4. However this doesn't help either since both dependencies greenlet and python 3.6 are already installed....